# How to add a given label to given node by using spring data neo4j?

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data, cypher

I use the spring data neo4j @query to add a label to a node, but there are some syntaxes. How can I transfer param correctly?

Such as :

```java
@Query("MATCH (st) WHERE st.originId = $originId SET st:$label RETURN st")  
public Node addLabel(String originId, String label);

@Query("MATCH (st) WHERE st.originId = $originId SET st:label RETURN st") 
public Node addLabel(String originId, @Param("label") String label);

@Query("MATCH (st) WHERE st.originId = $originId SET st:$1 RETURN st")
public Node addLabel(String originId, String label);
```

All of the above statements have errors.The compiler told me there was an error in ':'.

So, What's the correct statements?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, cypher does not support assigning dynamic node labels. You will need to use the APOC library:

```
MATCH (st) WHERE st.originId = $originId
CALL apoc.create.addLabels( [st], [$label​]) YIELD node
RETURN distinct 'done'
```

Comment: Thank you. I used the static value of Key Label to solve the problem. MATCH (st) WHERE st.originId = $originId SET st:KeyLabelName RETURN st